# Error while using conn = httplib.HTTPConnection ("http://ipaddr:port")

Tags: python, http

I am using

```
httplib.HTTPConnection ("http://ipaddr:port")  
conn.request("GET", "", params, headers)
```

I am able to do PUT/GET using ipaddr:port using my firefox client!!.
But I am seeing this error on execution of the script:

```
 File "post_python.py", line 5, in <module>
    conn.request("GET", "", params, headers)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 914, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 951, in _send_request
    self.endheaders()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 908, in endheaders
    self._send_output()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 780, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 739, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 720, in connect
    self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known"
```

Please can someone help me ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead (without "http://" before the IP address):

```
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("x.x.x.x", port)  
conn.request("GET", "", params, headers)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, but could u point me to any link where this is explained ??

http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html
I was referring to documentation and it said all the things below are the same !!!!

>h1 = httplib.HTTPConnection('www.cwi.nl')
>h2 = httplib.HTTPConnection('www.cwi.nl:80')
>h3 = httplib.HTTPConnection('www.cwi.nl', 80)
>h3 = httplib.HTTPConnection('www.cwi.nl', 80, timeout=10)

Comment: Yes, the documentation is correct.  Your error was to include "http://" before the IP address.  No big deal.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

You might have a proxy in between that the browser already knows about. If you're under linux try setting `http_proxy` environment variable.

Comment: @loan Alexandru Cucu:Thanks for the pointer, I just checked my browers proxy settings and there were none.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an IPv6 address, you need to surround it with brackets as per [RFC 2732](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2732.txt). If I recall correctly, that's the error message you get if you don't use brackets.

```
httplib.HTTPConnection ("http://[::1]:8080")  
conn.request("GET", "", params, headers)
```

Comment: Its not an IPV6 address,the prob is fixed by the above answer.Thanks

Comment: Then you should accept that answer, so your acceptance ratio stays high and so Alexandru gets his rating :)