# Trying to POST using a HTTP POST-request in python

Tags: python, http-post, httpconnection

I am trying to post two parameters using HTTP POST-request to http://foo.bar.com/submit.jsp.

This works.

```
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.bar.com")
conn.request("POST", "",parameters)
```

But this does not, could someone explain to me why it does not and how the correct way is?

```
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.foo.bar.com")
conn.request("POST", "/submit.jsp", parameters)
```

I am getting this error

```
File "example.py", line 68, in <module>
    conn.request("POST", "/submit.jsp", parameters)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 958, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 992, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 954, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 814, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 776, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 757, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: FYI: not an answer to your question but, I use the excellent Requests package (python-requests.org) for all HTTP client requirements I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever hostname you are really using in place of `www.foo.bar.com` can not be resolved to an IP address. Note that your first example used `www.bar.com`, not `www.foo.bar.com`. While these are only examples, the second hostname that you are using is bad.

The path `/submit.jsp` is not the problem here, if that is what you are actually trying to test?

Comment: Then how will I be able to POST to the hostname? As I mentioned in a comment below: I am supposed to get either an "OK" or "Err" back depending on the given parameters.

Comment: It looks like you are literally using those host names? If so, www.bar.com does exist. foo.bar.com is not a registered domain. It can not be resolved to an IP address and therefore can not be contacted.

Comment: Nono, I am not using those host names! :)

Comment: What is the second hostname? Are you certain that it is valid? If you have the host's IP address, try that instead.

Comment: SOLVED!
The problem was the "www." before foo.bar.com. A typo by me. Thank you kindly for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

This error means that python cannot reach the HTTP server you defined in the function, You could have a unneeded "HTTP://", A typo'd url, if you're using IPV6 it could be the form of your address or other network issues.

This might help;

[Error while using conn = httplib.HTTPConnection ("http://ipaddr:port")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836748/error-while-using-conn-httplib-httpconnection-http-ipaddrport)

Comment: I don't have any "HTTP://" in my url. I tried to ping www.bar.com, works fine. But I can't ping www.foo.bar.com. How shall I reach www.foo.bar.com/submit.jsp if I can't connect to www.foo.bar.com ?

Comment: Are you trying to post to a website that isn't your website?

Comment: Yes. It is schoolwork. The server is to respons with "OK" if my parameters are accurate, and "Err" if not